# If $\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x)-g(x)) = 0$ then $\lim_{x \to \infty} (f^2(x)-g^2(x)) = 0\ $: False?

Tags: calculus

> If $\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x)-g(x)) = 0$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} (f^2(x)-g^2(x)) = 0$

My teacher said that the above is false, but I can't find any example that shows that it's false! Can someone explain to me why it's false and also give an example?

Comment: You can show that if $f(x)$ is bounded, then the second limit is zero, too.

Answer (score 10):

Take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x+\dfrac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 1):

Another example: Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1}, g(x)=\sqrt{x}$.